# Firebase messaging not working for "data" messages in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an app running on iOS 9.3.5. I need to be able to send a push notification to my app when it's in the foreground or background. I don't actually need to include any data, I just need to ping the app so it will "*phone home*". So I don't need/want the user to see any notifications.

Since the company is already using Firebase for their Android app, I've set that up in the iOS app. If I send a message to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` with the `notification` key in the payload, it's received on the iPhone. When I try it with the `data` key instead, I get nothing. In both cases I get a `success` response from the POST. I've implemented the follow callbacks:

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:
applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage
```

None of those are called when sending a message with the `data` key.

Edit:
This is the payload I'm using.

> { "data": {
>      "message": "phonehome",
>    },
>    "to" : "xxxxx"
>   }

After doing some more testing it looks like I get that message when the app is in the foreground but not the background. When I switch to the foreground then `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` gets called.

Edit 2: Added `content_available` and that did the trick. Thanks!

> {   "to" : "xxxx", "content_available" : true }

Comment: Guess my suggestion worked. I deleted my comment modified it a little and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to suggest without a sample payload, However, do try to use the `priority` parameter as `high` or `content_available` to `true`.