# Firebase message notification not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using firebase to send notification to iOS and Android devices. Tried to send to native iOS app too, that didn't work either. The notifications are working just fine with Android but not reaching iOS devices.
What's weird is that the response from firebase is success. The same app is able to get notification from the [cordova site](http://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com)

Here are the request and response for FCM:

```
Request:{"data":{"title":"Test notification from server code","body":"detailContent : some test data"},"to":"foqwNQ2JATY:APA91bHZRz6L7z6q3zyItYBh0eNaMv25d0CPjzPfbT4tTRrxNrkdKYwQM2pqvB-Q7ry3AEwCs8IduuYVBz834muWXnwjvt5I7mbMPbpPCw17bbBqFG4hhNdqDIO0xRdDQir8P2hz66WE","priority":"high"}

Response:{"multicast_id":6317092041813746870,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1519618961399427%7c1174a8f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Comment: Try adding `"content_available" : true` to the message.  See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40004311/4815718

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work either. I copied the JSON from https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm to my SOAPUI project and trying to send notification. It is all weird now, those worked for a few transactions and then stopped working as I started to remove optional fields. And now even with all fields intact, it won't work. And I always get a success back.

Comment: The success response is only an indication that the server received and accepted your request and the token is valid.  It is not an indication that the message has been delivered to a device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your payload must be like:

```
{
"to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
"notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "myicon"
},
"data" : {
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}}
```

Having all data under data does not trigger any notification in iOS even though Firebase returns a successful request because the forwarded APNS payload is not correct.
Besides the proper way should be to follow the GCM or FCM payload recommendations, which is to use both notification for the notification message and data for custom key/value pairs.

When FCM Send data to APNS it convert it into APNs payload. It set values of notification in `aps` tag i.e.

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "body" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    }
},
"Nick" : "Mario",
"Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"   }
```

For More info please refer [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1828).

Comment: Ok looks good, I just got my test code working by adding notification object. However as per Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref Notification object is optional and if present, the notification is sent through APNs. Otherwise through FCM connection server. Shouldn't FCM connection server be used in case when Notification object is not present?

Comment: To send notification you need to send `aps` and `alert` tag because this is used to display data on notification center.  Here `title` is optional.

Comment: Got this now. So this is actually an FCM problem when it claims to be an intermediary, it should seamlessly support both Android and iOS with regards to format conversion. In Android, it's the data object that is taken up while in iOS it's the Notification object. Thanks for your inputs, this really helped

Comment: Would you know how to see what data is sent from FCM to APNs, like the JSON you posted. I'll need to get my iOS guys to check that since after adding "Notification" object, it started working for native iOS apps. Hybrid is still not showing the notification but am pretty sure it is reaching the device since it reached a native app, no reason it shouldn't reach a hybrid one.

Comment: I am not sure about JSON but you can check `userInfo` in notification. It shows complete dictionary object of received JSON.

Comment: Thanks, will pass this on to our mobile developers. We got this working for both android and iOS hybrid apps by sending same title and body keys in both Notification and Data objects.